# Incorporating TIPA-symbols into math mode

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, linguistics, tipa

I would like to create root symbols that have certain letters in them both from the TIPA package (for IPA symbols) but also letters like š. However, whenever I enter the respective codes for the forms into the maths environments, they are changed or displayed incorrectly (e.g. not italicised). Is there a way to incorporate `\usepackage{tipa}` into the math-mode(s) please?

Ultimately, it would be great to have roots like `$\sqrt{\textglotstop\v{s}r}$` displayed correctly.

Edit: I would also like to have commands such as \textsubdot{} and the following more complicated sign ḫ italicised in mathmode:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{tipa}{T3}{cmr}{m}{sl} 
\SetSymbolFont{tipa}{bold}{T3}{cmr}{bx}{sl}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathrtails}{\mathord}{tipa}{249}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathsci}{\mathord}{tipa}{73} \newcommand{\its}{{\mathsci\mathrtails}} 
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand*\U[1]{\oalign{#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-3ex}% \vbox to .2ex{\hbox{\u{}}\vss}\hidewidth}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define a math symbol font.

Look in `t3enc.def` for other glyphs to be used as math symbols. But never use `\v` or other text accents in math mode; the math accent corresponding to `\v` is `\check`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{tipa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{tipa}{m}{sl}{
  <-8.5> tipasl8
  <8.5-9.5> tipasl9
  <9.5-11> tipasl10
  <11-> tipasl12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{tipa}{U}{tipa}{m}{sl}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathglotstop}{\mathord}{tipa}{80}


\begin{document}

$\mathglotstop\check{s}r$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Extended coverage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{tipa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{tipa}{m}{sl}{
  <-8.5> tipasl8
  <8.5-9.5> tipasl9
  <9.5-11> tipasl10
  <11-> tipasl12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{tipa}{U}{tipa}{m}{sl}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathglotstop}{\mathord}{tipa}{80}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathrtails}{\mathord}{tipa}{249}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathsci}{\mathord}{tipa}{73}


\newcommand{\subdot}[1]{\underaccent{\dot}{#1}}
\newcommand{\subbreve}[1]{\underaccent{\breve}{#1}}

\newcommand{\its}{{\mathsci\mathrtails}}

\begin{document}

$\mathglotstop\check{s}r \mathrtails \subdot{x} \subbreve{h} \mathsci \its$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll add another question here, since I tried incorporating some other stuff from t3enc.def that hasn't worked so far. I would like to have both \textsubdot and a ḫ (h with below-breve) in the roots as well. The ḫ is already defined in math mode and works well apart from not italicising in the root.

Comment: This is the code I have for the h:

\DeclareSymbolFont{tipa}{T3}{cmr}{m}{sl}
\SetSymbolFont{tipa}{bold}{T3}{cmr}{bx}{sl}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathrtails}{\mathord}{tipa}{249}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathsci}{\mathord}{tipa}{73}

\newcommand{\its}{{\mathsci\mathrtails}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\U[1]{\oalign{#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-3ex}%
   \vbox to .2ex{\hbox{\u{}}\vss}\hidewidth}}
\makeatother

Comment: @Iris Accents should be added in a different way. But are you *really* sure you want to inflict such nonstandard symbols to your readers? Anyway, for subaccents, the `accents` package will help.

Comment: Yes, because this is the tradition of notation. If I do not use them I might get academically lynched. Thank you. :)

Comment: @Iris Please, add to your question the other thing you need

Comment: Done, thank you.

Comment: @Iris Added the requested glyphs.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked.